# show a hierarchy similar to file system in tree view, generics involved

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have some classes representing a user library. They look like this:

```
public class UserLibraryData
{
    public IList<Node<UserDataEntry>> Nodes { get; private set; }
    ...
}

public class Node<T>
{
    public IList<Node<T>> SubNodes { get; private set; }
    public IList<T> Entries { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    ...
}

public class UserDataEntry
{
    string ViewName { get; private set;}
    ...
}
```

So it is like a file system with folders (nodes) and files (entries).

Now I want to represent that data in a TreeView. I wrote a XAML file that has an instance of `UserLibraryData` as its DataContext. For the TreeView, I wrote this:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubNodes}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

But as expected, it only shows the nodes and subnodes, not the entries. I tried to add another `DataTemplate` to the `TreeViewTemplate`, but it seems I can only define one such template.

So how do I also show the entries of nodes in each layer?

EDIT:

Assume we have the following UserLibraryData:

```
Node1 -> contains Node2, Node3 and Entry1, Entry2
Node2 -> contains Entry3, Entry4
Node3 -> contains Node4
Node4 -> contains Entry5
Node5 -> contains nothing
```

This is my expected output (when all nodes are expanded):

```
Node1
    Node2
        Entry3
        Entry4
    Node3
        Node4
            Entry5
    Entry1
    Entry2
Node5
```

EDIT2:

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39721198/5333340 would have solved my issue if the `Node` class was not generic. Unfortunately, `DataType="{x:Type ...}"` does not allow generic types, as I learned from other SO threads. A common workaround is to create a child class like this

```
public class NodeUserDataEntry : Node<UserDataEntry> { ... }
```

and then replace every occurrence of `Node<UserDataEntry>` by `NodeUserDataEntry`. However, a lot of code has already been written that makes heavy use of the genericness of `Node`. So to change the type from `Node<UserDataEntry>` to `NodeUserDataEntry` is like writing the whole application anew. Isn't there another way where I can just keep my already written code of `UserLibraryData`, `Node<T>` and `UserDataEntry` as it is and only extend it, maybe by some converter/wrapper?

Comment: Do you want the `Entires` to be displayed as a list along side the `Nodes` or do you want to display someting like `Node : Entry` ?

Answer (score 1):

I took your data structure and added something missing in order it to be working.

Your issue is the following...
When you build your `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, you can't select two lists as `ItemsSource`. So, you can't tell your template to show both `SubNodes` and `Entries` from a `Node`.

In order to be able to build your `TreeView`, you have to construct an unique `List` containing objects of both `Entries` and `SubNodes`.

I called it `Childrens`. (Add this in Nodes Class).

```
  public List<object> Childrens
    {
        get 
        {
            _childrens = new List<object>();
            foreach (var subNode in SubNodes)
            {
                _childrens.Add(subNode);
            }
            foreach (var userDataEntry in Entries)
            {
                _childrens.Add(userDataEntry);
            }
            return _childrens;
        }
        private set { _childrens = value; }
    }
```

After this you have to change your XAML.

I declare the templates as ressources, and thanks to the `DataTypes`, the templates will be resolved by at run time.

We want to show:

- `Name` from Class `Node`.
- `ViewName` from Class `Entry`.
- `Subnodes` and `Entries` included in the `Childrens` property from Class `Node`. (Which expose both previous properties).

  ```
  <Grid.Resources>

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childrens}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserDataEntry}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewName}"/>
      </DataTemplate>

  </Grid.Resources>
  ```

Assuming your DataContext is set to your Class UserLibraryData, you have to declare your TreeView this way :

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}"/>
```

And you should have this result :

[image]

Comment: I still can't get it to work. First, regarding the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`the compiler says it cannot find the type `Node` although it IS there (I double-checked that the namespace is correct). Does this have maybe something to do with the fact that my `Node` doesn't have a default (parameterless) constructor? Second, I cannot put two DataTeplates into the TreeView. You somehow managed to do this with `Grid.Resources`. But then, how do you make the `TreeView` use these resources?

Comment: Even if I add a parameterless constructor of Node, it still complains that it cannot find that type...

Comment: Or maybe it is because in my real application, `Node` is generic? If this is the case, is there any way to work around that? I know I can define a nongeneric child class of my generic `Node<T>`, but then I have to change a hell lot of code...

Comment: Too bad you can't make it work. In the TreeView, I showed you what is in my code. I didn't put any DataTemplate. This is resolved by itself, by type.

Comment: I don't see anything to do with constructor. About generic, I didn't try, what do you mean by generic on Node, is it an interface/ abstract class ?

Comment: I updated my question. Please do not remove your answer - but instead put some comment at the top that it was given when the OP had not mentioned generics yet. It helped me a lot already, thanks!. Unfortunately it seems that whenever one issue in WPF is solved, a new one comes up that one was not aware of before... (I didn't mention the genericness of `Node<T>` before because I thought it was irrelevant for my problem, and I wanted to keep my question simple.)

Answer (score 0):

I found another workaround:

- add the `Childrens` property to class `Node<T>` as suggested by answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39721198/5333340 .
- Rename the property `ViewName` of class `UserDataEntry` into `Name`.
- Change the `ItemsSource` of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to `"{Binding Childrens}"`

Since the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in my XAML code does not have a `DataType` attribute set, it is used for all elements of the `Childrens` collection (both `Node<T>` and `UserDataEntry`), and since both have the property `Name`, it is shown for all of them.

This is much easier than changing types everywhere in the code.

But still I am interested in a solution where I do not need to change the already existing code, only extend it.